# Does the Overload ability actually do damage to or remove shields on cast?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In single player the Overload ability seems to ALWAYS completely remove the target's shield. So I ask then, what is the value of leveling up the damage of the ability if I only want to use it to remove shields (using incinerate to do damage after the shield has been destroyed)? Should I take the recharge speed upgrades if shield removal is my only intended use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your main use is to remove the Shield or Barrier, it's indeed **best to take the recharge speed upgrade**, or the multiple overload bonus.

Don't forget that overload do also damages to the synthetics!

Answer (score 0):

Negative. Unless you grab full damage on it, playing on Insanity will not drain a lot of the low level shields instantly. Tested with Garrus and EDI on multiple playthroughs, EDI having max damage and Garrus having Chain Overload.